# check NGINX version at configuration file level

Tags: nginx, version, nginx-config

Is there a constant that holds the **nginx version** (and which format is used) I can access from the configuration file to set conditional options based on the detected version?

Edit: this was an easy one... `$nginx_version`

However I'm stuck again:

in an `http` block I have:

```
    if $nginx_version ~ .*1\.22.*
    {
        server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64;
    }
```

older but it complains I cannot use `if` there

I have two different nginx instances running on two separate servers, the older one doesn't understand `server_names_hash_bucket_size`

It's not time to upgrade and align the two severs.

But it would convenient for me to use the same config